# Excel Calculate Measure in Pivot and sum and then calculation

Tags: excel, dax, pivot-table

I am trying to use calculate the number of pupils that received 6 or more grades at grade 9-5 in a pivot table using a measure and not really suceeding.

The columns I have data in are:

| CandidateNumber | GradeInt |
| --- | --- |
| 123457 | 7 |
| 123457 | 2 |
| 123457 | 9 |
| 123457 | 3 |
| 123457 | 9 |
| 123457 | 8 |
| 123457 | 8 |
| 123457 | 4 |
| 123456 | 9 |
| 123456 | 8 |
| 123456 | 9 |
| 123456 | 8 |
| 123456 | 9 |
| 123456 | 8 |
| 123456 | 4 |
| 123456 | 8 |

Canidate numner 123456 would be counted as having 6+ grades whereas 123457 would because they only have 5 grades between 9-5.

The following measure works but only when I have the CandidateNumber showing as a row group:

=IF(CALCULATE([Count of GradeInt], ALL_for_Pivot[GradeInt]>4)>=6,1,0)

What I would like to do is just show the overall number of pupils that have got 9-5 rather than a line by line 1 or 0 appearing which I then have to summarise.

Any ideas please.

Thanks,

Comment: Add a helper column to handle assessing the grades and then use the pivot table to summarize.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting each student's passing grade count first, like this:

```
Passing Grade Count = COUNTROWS(
FILTER('factGrades',[GradeInt]>4) )
```

and then I just got a count of students with the requisite number of passing grades, like this:

```
Successful Student Count = COUNTROWS(
              FILTER('DimCandidate',[Passing Grade Count]>5) )
```

Comment: thank you but the data for candidates and grades is in one table called 'All_for_pivot'. When I add the Successful Student Count to the pivot it just appears blank.

Comment: That's because I created a table of the unique students and put that in a separate table, DimCandidate